# Latitude and Longitude values not displayng in TextView

Tags: android, xml, geolocation

I'm writing an application where a user can fill out a form on an activity and sync it to a web service. Part of the application involves geolocation, so, lat and long value. I want my application to automatically the geolocation of a person's smartphone (it does this successfully) and then automatically fill in a TextView on the activity's form. I've tried some methods out but to no avail. Could anyone advise me on where I'm going wrong?

Here is the DataEntry class:-

```
package application.prototype.mfb;

import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import application.prototype.mfb.MyLocation.LocationResult;

/**
 * Records a new data form entry for a favourite building
 * @author DanielD
 *
 */
public class DataEntry extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

Button btnClear;  
Button btnSync;
EditText txtBuildingName;
EditText txtDescription;
TextView txtLongitude;
TextView txtLatitude;
Spinner project;

public static Location loc;
private static double longitude;
private static double latitude;
private static String name;
private static String description; 
private static String projectString;
private static String lngString = String.valueOf(longitude);
private static String latString = String.valueOf(latitude);

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_data_entry);

    LocationResult locationResult = new LocationResult(){
        @Override
        public void gotLocation(Location location){
            loc = location;
            latitude = loc.getLatitude();
            longitude = loc.getLongitude();
            System.out.println("Latitude: " + latitude);
            System.out.println("Longitude: " + longitude);
        }
    };
        MyLocation myLocation = new MyLocation();
        myLocation.getLocation(DataEntry.this, locationResult);

    txtBuildingName=(EditText)this.findViewById(R.id.nameContent);
    txtDescription=(EditText)this.findViewById(R.id.descriptionContent);

    project=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.type_project);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapterTwo = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.type_project_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    project.setAdapter(adapterTwo);

    txtLatitude=(TextView)this.findViewById(R.id.TextViewLat);
    txtLongitude=(TextView)this.findViewById(R.id.TextViewLong);

    /*These checks will ensure that if a variable still has user data in it, it will refill the fields with that data preventing users entering
     * the same information multiple times
     */
    if(name != null){
        txtBuildingName.setText(name);
    }

    if(description != null){
        txtDescription.setText(description);
    }

    if(projectString != null){
        project.getItemAtPosition(project.getSelectedItemPosition()).toString();
    }

    if(latString != null){
        txtLatitude.setText(latString);
    }

    if(lngString != null){
        txtLongitude.setText(lngString);
    }

    btnClear=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnClear);
    btnClear.setOnClickListener(this);

    btnSync=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSync);
    btnSync.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v){                                        //NEW VERSION OF COMMIT DATA - WILL PRESERVE DATA OVER ACTIVITY
            if(txtBuildingName.getText().toString().length() > 0)
                name = txtBuildingName.getText().toString();
            if(txtDescription.getText().toString().length() > 0)
                description = txtDescription.getText().toString();
            if(project.getItemAtPosition(project.getSelectedItemPosition()).toString().length() > 0)
                projectString = project.getItemAtPosition(project.getSelectedItemPosition()).toString();
            Intent intent = new Intent(DataEntry.this, DataSummary.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });    
}

public static String getName(){
    return name;
}

public static String getDescription(){
    return description;
}

public static String getLongitude(){
    return lngString;
}

public static String getLatitude(){
    return latString;
}

/*public Location getLongitude(){
     LocationManager lm = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
     Location location = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
     longitude = location.getLongitude();
     return longitude;
 }

public Location getLatitude(){
    LocationManager lm = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    Location location = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    latitude = location.getLatitude();
    latitudeString = String.valueOf(latitude);
    return latitudeString;

}*/

public static String getProject(){
    return projectString;
}

public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState){
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}

public void onRestoredInstanceState(Bundle returnState)
{
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(returnState);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_favourite_building, menu);
    return true;
}

public void onClick(View v){
    switch(v.getId())
    {
    case R.id.btnClear : clearFields();
    break;  
    }
}

/**
 * Switch statement governing the different options available on the Action Bar
 */
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
    switch(item.getItemId()){
    case R.id.app_camera:
        Intent intentZero = new Intent(this, CameraDemo.class);
        intentZero.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(intentZero);
        return true;

    case R.id.app_dataentry:  
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, DataEntry.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(intent);
        return true;

    case R.id.app_syncorsave:
        Intent intentOne = new Intent(this, DataSummary.class);
        intentOne.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(intentOne);
        return true;

    case R.id.app_discard:  
        Intent intentTwo = new Intent(this, DeleteProjects.class);
        intentTwo.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(intentTwo);
        return true;

    case R.id.app_homescreen:
        Intent intentThree = new Intent(this, ProjectGrid.class);
        intentThree.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(intentThree);
        return true;

    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

 public void clearFields(){
        Toast.makeText(DataEntry.this, "All fields Reset", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        txtBuildingName.getEditableText().clear();
        txtDescription.getEditableText().clear();
        name = "";              //must also set the static variables to blank otherwise previous data still assigned in variable.
        description = "";
        projectString = ""; 
    }
}
```

And here is the MyLocation.java class:-

```
package application.prototype.mfb;

import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
import android.content.Context;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MyLocation {
Timer timer1;
LocationManager lm;
LocationResult locationResult;
boolean gps_enabled=false;
boolean network_enabled=false;

public boolean getLocation(Context context, LocationResult result)
{
    //I use LocationResult callback class to pass location value from MyLocation to user code.
    locationResult=result;
    if(lm==null)
        lm = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    //exceptions will be thrown if provider is not permitted.
    try
    {
        gps_enabled=lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    try
    {
        network_enabled=lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    //don't start listeners if no provider is enabled
    if(!gps_enabled && !network_enabled)
        return false;

    if(gps_enabled)
        lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListenerGps);
    if(network_enabled)
        lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListenerNetwork);
    timer1=new Timer();
    timer1.schedule(new GetLastLocation(), 20000);
    return true;
}

LocationListener locationListenerGps = new LocationListener() 
{
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) 
    {
        timer1.cancel();
        locationResult.gotLocation(location);



      //  lm.removeUpdates(this);
        //lm.removeUpdates(locationListenerNetwork);
    }
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}
};

LocationListener locationListenerNetwork = new LocationListener()
{
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) 
    {
        timer1.cancel();
        locationResult.gotLocation(location);
       // lm.removeUpdates(this);
     //   lm.removeUpdates(locationListenerGps);
    }
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}
};

class GetLastLocation extends TimerTask 
{
    @Override
    public void run() {
         //lm.removeUpdates(locationListenerGps);
         //lm.removeUpdates(locationListenerNetwork);

         Location net_loc=null, gps_loc=null;
         if(gps_enabled)
             gps_loc=lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
         if(network_enabled)
             net_loc=lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

         //if there are both values use the latest one
         if(gps_loc!=null && net_loc!=null){
             if(gps_loc.getTime()>net_loc.getTime())
                 locationResult.gotLocation(gps_loc);
             else
                 locationResult.gotLocation(net_loc);
             return;
         }

         if(gps_loc!=null){
             locationResult.gotLocation(gps_loc);
             return;
         }
         if(net_loc!=null){
             locationResult.gotLocation(net_loc);
             return;
         }
         locationResult.gotLocation(null);
    }
}

public static abstract class LocationResult
{
    public abstract void gotLocation(Location location);
}
}
```

Now I've added the `System.out.println` methods in to identify in the logcat log whether the location values have been found and they have (see below). So how do I take those values and convert them into a suitable format to display in the TextView?

`01-11 18:04:01.885: I/System.out(541): Latitude: -4.066498333333333`

`01-11 18:04:01.885: I/System.out(541): Longitude: 52.410999999999994`

*taken as an exert from the resulting logcat file.

Comment: you only have to set the textfields with your coords

Comment: What do you mean by Suitable format??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So how do I take those values and convert them into a suitable format to display in the TextView?

Displaying them is easy, you've done 98% of the work, just add:

```
LocationResult locationResult = new LocationResult(){
    @Override
    public void gotLocation(Location location){
        loc = location;
        latitude = loc.getLatitude();
        longitude = loc.getLongitude();

        txtLatitude.setText(latitude + "");
        txtLongitude.setText(longitude + "");

        System.out.println("Latitude: " + latitude);
        System.out.println("Longitude: " + longitude);
    }
};
```

But "suitable format" is a little vague... What format do you want?  You can use [`Location.convert()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#convert%28double,%20int%29) to use a more traditional `hour:minute:second.fraction` format.

Comment: Sorry to be vague by suitable format I just meant one that complies with a TextView so a String in essence. Thanks for your help it worked a treat. Correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
TextView tvLongitude=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewlongitude);         
TextView tvLatitude=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewlatitude); 
tvLongitude.setText("Longitude is"+longitude );
tvLatitude.setText("Latitude is"+latitude );
```

in this way you can set values on textview

Answer (score 0):

Mmmm, watching quickly your code, you are printing in System.out the double value that you are receiving in the Result callback, but you are never filling both String vars that you are trying to put on the TextViews.

You should refill your vars on the Location callback

```
  LocationResult locationResult = new LocationResult(){
        @Override
        public void gotLocation(Location location){
            loc = location;
            latitude = loc.getLatitude();
            longitude = loc.getLongitude();
            lngString = String.valueOf(longitude);
            latString = String.valueOf(latitude);
            System.out.println("Latitude: " + latitude);
            System.out.println("Longitude: " + longitude);
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

To Make this display on textview

Your Layout `activity_data_entry.xml`

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewlatitude"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewlongitude"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Inside Code:

```
LocationResult locationResult = new LocationResult(){
    @Override
    public void gotLocation(Location location){
        loc = location;
        latitude = loc.getLatitude();
        longitude = loc.getLongitude();

        TextView tvLongitude=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewlongitude);
        TextView tvLatitude=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewlatitude);

        tvLongitude.setText("Longitude is"+longitude );
        tvLatitude.setText("Latitude is"+latitude );
    }
};
```

But what do you mean by suitable format??